# Distribution of polynomial after projections

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, random-variables, finite-fields

I asked a somewhat similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3648690/expected-number-of-monomials-in-a-random-function-over-finite-fields#comment7500777_3648690), but I believe this one is different enough for its own post.

Let $p : \{1,2 \}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_3$ be a polynomial chosen uniformly at random (every coefficient is chosen uniformly at random from $\mathbb{Z}_3$). Suppose that $q : \{1,2\}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_3$ was obtain from $p$ by fixing all but $m$ variables, chosen arbitrarily (e.g. $q(x_1,\ldots, x_m) = p(x_1,\ldots,x_m, 1,2,1,1,..,2)$).

Does the distribution of $q$'s is also uniform over the polynomials with $m$ variables? More specifically, does $q$ have properties of a random polynomial (e.g. expected number of monomials, degree, etc.)?

Seems to me that the answer is yes, since this operation is a projection onto a subspace of dimension $m$, and a projection of a random vector is a random vector in the projected subspace. Yet I am not sure if this argument holds for an arbitrary projection (and not just for a random projection).

Comment: Yes. The claim is obvious for the set of all functions, and (see my answer to your previous question) here every function comes from a polynomial. Of course, if you draw polynomials from a finite set that does not intersect the cosets of the key ideal $I=\langle x_i^2-1\mid i=1,2,\ldots,n\rangle$ uniformly, then you will get non-uniformity here also.

Comment: Thanks! May you please explain the last claim? If I draw a polynomial uniformly at random, why does the property you mentioned hold?